# Разное поведение при одинаковом вводе

Tags: функции, bash

Есть функция `search`

```bsh
search(){
    echo "$1"
    # If directory -> recursion
    # If file and regex ok -> echo
    for file in "$1"/*; do
        ([[ -d "$file" ]] && search "$file" $2 ||
                 if [[ ( -f "$file" ) && ( "$file" =~ $2 ) ]];
                     then
                         echo "$file"
                     fi)
    done
}
```

Если вызывать ее от параметров командной строки: `search "$1" "$2"` `./s.sh . *`, то вывод будет таким:

```
> ./s.sh . *
.
./a
./aaa.mp3
./a_directory
./a_directory/aaa.aaa
./a_directory/another_file
./a_directory/b
./alala.txt
./alphabet.txt
./a.sh
```

Но если вызывать напрямую задавая параметры `search "." "*"`, то вывод окажется:

```
> ./s.sh . *
.
./a_directory
./a_directory/aaa.aaa
./a_directory/another_file
./a_directory/b
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` без кавычек - это глоб, разворачивающийся в список содержимого папки. Cоответственно в первом случае у вас передается не обязательно два аргумента, и второй, даже если и есть, то не будет `*`.

Comment: Лишний раз напоминание писать *#!/bin/sh -efu*.